# Excel - Copy data from multiple sheets to one sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I use a program that exports data to multiple sheets and I need these all in the same sheet under one another.

About the worksheets - They vary in names every export, so this needs not be defined, as there are sometimes 100+ different sheets.

Inside the worksheets - Is data of varying rows and columns (and I need it to copy until blank row into the main sheet at the next available row that is blank).

The worksheet that all the data needs to be copied too - This will initially be blank, however I need all the data on top of one another based on a row copy from the other worksheets. (this can have a defined name if required)

I'm new to VBA, so hopefully explanation above helps.

My current VBA not working:

```
 Sub SheetLoopPasteData()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim wsSheet As Worksheet
Set wsSheet = Sheets("Sheet2")

For Each ws In Worksheets
    ws.Activate
    variable = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Rows("1:" & variable).Copy _
    Destination:=wsSheet.Range("A" & (wsSheet.Range("A" & wsSheet.Rows.Count).End(xlDown).Row + 1))

Next



End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*I would like to suggest VBA (Macro) will help you to Copy used range from all Worksheets into New, exactly works as Data Consolidation.*

```
Sub CombineData()

    Dim I As Long
    Dim xRg As Range

    On Error Resume Next

    Worksheets.Add Sheets(1)

    ActiveSheet.Name = "MasterSheet"

   For I = 2 To Sheets.Count
        Set xRg = Sheets(1).UsedRange

        If I > 2 Then
            Set xRg = Sheets(1).Cells(xRg.Rows.Count + 1, 1)
        End If

        Sheets(I).Activate
        ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Copy xRg
    Next

End Sub
```

**How it works:**

- **Copy** & **Paste** this code as Module.
- Macro will create new sheet in existing Workbook named as **MasterSheet**, which is editable.
- In place of copy data from Top Row to last, I've used the **UsedRange** method, since will accommodate every updates.

Comment: Incredible, this is exactly what I was after. Thank you.

Comment: Glad to help you @John,, keep asking ☺

Comment: Hi Rajesh, I hope this finds you well. It seems my data is cut off at 64740 lines or 20 odd sheets. I have 800k lines total and 150+ sheets. Thoughts?

Comment: Ignore me Rajesh, I wish there was a way to make everything convert to the latest version of excel without me thinking about it. Annoying compatibility mode.

Comment: @John,, it doesn't matters how many Rows & Columns Sheets does have and also number of sheets,, this code will copy all data from the used range (the portion of Sheet recently updated) to the Master Sheet,,, yes I could scene one possibility that is speed since you are suppose to use large number of Sheets,, so ultimately all dependents on the speed of Computer you are working with,,, !!

Comment: **Cont,,** my suggestion is divide sheets into few workbooks then try the code, will reduce time and get speed too ☺

Comment: Thanks all, very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

this is very good however I need it to cope a specific range - can it be done please?

---

I would like to suggest VBA (Macro) will help you to Copy used range from all Worksheets into New, exactly works as Data Consolidation.

Sub CombineData()

```
Dim I As Long
Dim xRg As Range

On Error Resume Next

Worksheets.Add Sheets(1)

ActiveSheet.Name = "MasterSheet"
```

For I = 2 To Sheets.Count
        Set xRg = Sheets(1).UsedRange

```
    If I > 2 Then
        Set xRg = Sheets(1).Cells(xRg.Rows.Count + 1, 1)
    End If

    Sheets(I).Activate
    ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Copy xRg
Next
```

End Sub
How it works:

Copy & Paste this code as Module.
Macro will create new sheet in existing Workbook named as MasterSheet, which is editable.
In place of copy data from Top Row to last, I've used the UsedRange method, since will accommodate every updates.