# Copying data from multiple sheets into single sheet using VBA where the data is copied into different rows

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I am trying to write a macro using VBA where I go through each worksheet and copy the data into one main sheet `(Sheet7)`.

But there are multiple sheets where the data are in the same ranges and I don't want the data to overlap in the main sheet. So I am trying to create a macro where the copied data moves down a row as the code runs through each sheet. My code so far is not working. Here's what I have so far.

```
Sub copyrecursive()

Dim ws As Worksheet    
Dim R As Range

For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets

    For Each R In Range("A1:E2").Rows               
        ws.Range("A1:E1").copy                
        Worksheets("Sheet7").R.PasteSpecial           
    Next R

Next ws    

End Sub
```

So I want the range `A1:E1` in `Sheet1` to copy to `Sheet7 A1:E1` and then I want the range `A1:E1` in `Sheet2` to copy to `Sheet7 A2:E2`. Hope this is a good enough explanation. Thank you for any help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Excel - Copy data from multiple sheets to one sheet](https://superuser.com/questions/1455592/excel-copy-data-from-multiple-sheets-to-one-sheet)

Answer (score 0):

1. you need to qualify which worksheet you are working on
2. you need to keep a row counter for the row you will paste the data on
3. no need to copy, you can assign the values directly
4. you need to check the worksheet name to not copy `A1:E1` of `sheet7`

   ```
   Sub copyrecursive()

   Dim ws As Worksheet
   Dim R As Range
   Dim i as long

   i = 1
   For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
       if ws.name <> "Sheet7" then
           Worksheets("Sheet7").Range("A" & i & ":E" & i).value = ws.Range("A1:E1").value
           i = i + 1
       end if
   Next ws

   End Sub
   ```

Comment: When I run this code in the line i + i + 1 turns into i i + 1 and I get an "Expected sub, function, or property error". Any thoughts? Thanks

Comment: That was a typo, see my edit: `i = i + 1`

Comment: Yes I figured this and made the switch. Now that the code work however it produces no results on Sheet7.

Comment: Works fine on my machine

Comment: Yeah it works now. For some reason just retyping it all out worked. Thank you for your help.